# How to drag and drop an external item for Xcode-ui-testing

Tags: swift, xcode, drag-and-drop, xcuitest

In my application I allow the user to drag and drop items from Finder (or any other source of a file based URL) into my application. What I want to do is to add a mechanism that will allow me to test this in the Xcode UI testing.

I can see how to use `XCUIElement.press(forDuration:thenDragTo:)` to test the drag and drop of a source and destination within the application, but I have been unable to find a way to test when the source of the drag is outside of the application.

In a somewhat related test, I test the copy and paste portion of the application by setting the string I want to paste into `NSPasteboard.general`, then using `XCUIElement.typeKey("v", modifierFlags: .command)` to paste it into the desired element. That is a little less than ideal as it depends on Command-v actually being implemented as the paste command, but that is unlikely to change so it is acceptable for my needs. (In fact I've written an `XCUIElement.paste(_ s: String)` extension that makes it easy for me to add this in a test.)

I believe that drag and drop is also using an `NSPasteboard` for its communications, so with a little investigation into the underlying mechanism, I should be able to set my object into the correct pasteboard just like I do for the cut and paste. I'm reasonably certain I can figure that part out. But I haven't figured out how to perform the actual drop.

My goal would be to create an `XCUIElement.drop(_ url)` that would setup the proper "public.file-url" object into the correct pasteboard, and then simulate/perform the drop into the element.

Any ideas?

I should note that I have already tried the following two items:

First, I did use the Xcode record feature to attempt to record the drag and drop operation and see what events it would give me. Unfortunately, it records absolutely nothing.

Second, I do have a menu based alternative where the user selects a file via the file selector. So if I could simulate the file selection, that would be a suitable testing alternative for my purposes. Unfortunately, I didn't make any progress along that path either. When I used Xcode to record the events, it recorded the menu selection, nothing that was actually done in the dialog.

Comment: Why `XCUIElement.press(forDuration:thenDragTo:)` did not work?

Comment: There are two reasons that I don't believe the `press` will work. First, what element do I press? That should be the source element, but in my case the source element is outside of the application. Second, how would I specify the contents that are to be dragged? Presumably that would be based on the element that is the source, but as I mentioned, I don't have such an element. I suppose one option could be to create an invisible label or something when the application is in "debug" mode, and use that as the source. But that seems like a terrible "hack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I would recommend you to read this article documentation piece
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication

Notice the `init(bundleIdentifier: String)` and `init(url: URL)` methods. These allow you to interact with apps apart from the target application.

Then you can use `XCUIElement.press(forDuration:thenDragTo:)`

```swift
import XCTest
import XCTApps
import ScreenObject

let notes = XCTApps.notes.app
let photos = XCTApps.photos.app

class Tests: XCTestCase {
    func testDragAndDrop() {
        photos.launch()
        notes.launch()
        photos.images.lastMatch.press(forDuration: 1, thenDragTo: notes.textViews["Note Body Text View"])
    }
}
```

P.S. In this example I use XCTApps because I don't want to remember or google bundle identifiers :D

https://github.com/rzakhar/XCTApps

Comment: Very interesting. This looks like it is exactly what I wanted to do. I will play with this a bit later today.

Comment: Well this definitely answers my question. It isn't going to be quite as easy for me to use in my instance, but I think I can figure it out. (Specifically, how to get the item I want from Finder in order to drag it, and how to close the Finder window I've opened without closing them all.)

So I'm not sure I'm actually going to use it in my test case right away, but I will accept the answer as it is certainly the correct answer to my question.

Comment: I'm guessing that `import ScreenObject` is what provides the `lastMatch` method? I've done a quick GitHub search to find it without success, nor does it show up in the Apple developer docs. Could you provide a reference on where to find it? Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Grab ScreenObject here https://github.com/devexperts/screenobject

Comment: Thanks, it looks very useful. Odd that it didn’t show up in my search yesterday. Today I repeat the search and it’s the second item on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I haven't yet figured out the answer to my question (how to test a drag and drop), but I have come up with an acceptable workaround for my test.

Specifically, as I thought more about the pasteboard I realized that if I'm allowing the user to drag and drop a file into my application, then I should also be allowing them to cut and paste a file into the application.

Once I had that realization, then it was a reasonably simple process to test the necessary feature of my application by pasting a URL instead of dragging and dropping the URL. This has the added advantage that I can add the necessary test file to my testing package, keeping everything nicely self contained.

To this end I've added the following function to my XCUIElement extension:

```
extension XCUIElement {
    func paste(url: URL) {
        precondition(url.isFileURL, "This must be a file URL to match the pasteboard type.")
        let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
        pasteboard.clearContents()
        pasteboard.setString(url.absoluteString, forType: .fileURL)
        click()
        typeKey("v", modifierFlags: .command)
    }
}
```

Then in my test code I add the following to trigger the event:

```
let mainWindow = app.windows[/*...my main window name goes here...*/]
let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let fileURL = testBundle.url(forResource: "Resources/simple", withExtension: "json")
mainWindow.paste(url: fileURL!)
```

Granted, this doesn't actually test the drag and drop, but it does test the same portion of my code, since in my `AppDelegate` I have my `onPaste` action method calling the same underlying method as my `performDrop` method.

I will wait a couple of days to see if anyone comes up with an answer to the actual question (since I would still find that useful), but if no one does, I'll accept my own answer.